# como cambiar el icono del marcador si estoy usando los plugins gmaps jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

[image: codigo de Gmaps jQuery un plugin para mostrar ubicaciones en tu sitio web]

---

Por favor, ¿hay la manera de cambiar el icono del marcador utilizando estas etiquetas HTML?. Así como data-icon="pueda poner cualquier imagen". Ya que vi varias formas de como cambiar el icono del marcador pero no utiliza estas etiquetas HTML.

---

el código completo se encuentra aquí
http://develoteca.com/gmaps-jquery-plugin-mostrar-ubicaciones-en-sitio-web/

Comment: revisa la sig. url: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers?hl=es

Comment: gracias por el interés Jose, pero ya lo vi, es un código muy aparte eso creo, en este código que me recomiendas no entra las etiquetas html